# Does cp -r do the same thing as cp -recurse?

Tags: powershell

Just started learning shell scripting..just a bit confused between the two. they seem to be doing the same operation? Can someone provide any example to show their different workings?
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. it does.

Cmdlet parameters can be shortened as far as they are unambiguous. Since `-Recurse` is the only parameter of `Copy-Item` that starts with `R` all of the following would do the same:

```
-Recurse
-Recurs
-Recur
-Recu
-Rec
-Re
-R
```

However, this is mainly to aid interactive typing (as are aliases). In scripts you *should* usually rely on the cmdlet names and the full parameter names because when a parameter is added that conflicts with your use of a shortened parameter your script would stop working (mind you, this is no guarantee; for a while PSCX added a different `Get-Random` cmdlet even to PowerShell 2. thus overriding the built-in one – you could use the full cmdlet names, but that becomes unwieldy quickly).

Comment: O_o The PSCX guys should prefix their nouns... *cough* @KeithHill lol